# Getting the length of a string after reading from buffer

Tags: c++, string, stl

```
string str;
stringstream buffer;

buffer << is.rdbuf();

str = buffer.str();

cout << str.length();
size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of(".123456789");
```

Can someone please explain to me why this code doesn't work?

When I run it, it just sits there after I enter "12345"

What on earth is going on?! I'm not too familiar with stringstreams but why wouldn't this, and other seemingly mundane operations work as expected?

Comment: Are you just trying to read a single word or line?

Comment: I'm trying to read everything that's in standard input.  The reason I'm not using the standard getline(is, str) is because I want to read in escape characters as well.  But, alas, I am running into these headaches when dealing with streams.

Comment: Hitting enter doesn't finish the input.

Comment: right.  I understand the concept of the stream remaining open.  After all my goal was to read in escape characters, and I am reading in a \n now, but not closing the stream.  I cannot find any function that will manually close it for me, however, so my problem remains.  I have tried is.close()  [doesn't work] and I can't find any close function for stringstream.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expecting something to happen when you press enter?  That only ends one line, not the whole input.  If you want something to happen when you hit enter, you need to read a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
string str;
getline(is,str);
cout << str.length();
size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of(".123456789");
```

Comment: @ordinary: Under Linux, if I hit escape, then that becomes part of str.  For example, if I hit escape and then press enter, str contains a single escape character.  I'm not sure what platform you are using.

Comment: What escape sequences? Like literal '\' followed by literal 'n'? Sure it will read in those too!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to close the stream, i.e. Ctrl+D or something.
Remember that for streams, newline is just another (two) character(s).

So you probably need to use different input stream reader which can treat lines.
I don't know STD lib that well but I bet it's there.

Comment: For text streams (and all streams except fstreams opened in binary mode are text streams), newline is a single character.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by not reading escape sequences? getline will read everything as you type. Consider the following example (bit ugly as you mix C and C++ constructs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
        std::string str;
        getline(std::cin,str);
        printf("string length: %ld\n",str.length());
        size_t pos = str.find_first_not_of(".123456789");
        printf("first nondigit: %ld\n",pos);
        printf("you typed: %s\n",str.c_str());
        return 0;
}
```

If I run it and type in

```
12345\n\t a
```

I get the following output:

```
string length: 11
first nondigit: 5
you typed: 12345\n\t a
```

Answer (score 0):

cin waits for a separator character to be entered. Press Enter when you finished entering a string.